# Importing NumPy to Python2.7 in Geany Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, windows-7-x64, amd-processor, geany

I am using 64 bit windows 7 running on an AMD processor.

I have installed [python-2.7.3.amd64](http://www.python.org/getit/).

I have installed the pertinent (UN-official) binaries of [NumPy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

When I import numpy and start calling its functions through the python command line everything works fine.

However when I do the same while I am in the Geany editor an error message tells that python does not now any module under the name of numpy:

> ImportError: No module named numpy

as I reinstalled both python and numpy twice and nothing changed.

I wonder the problem may raising from the fact that Geany has some incompatibilities either with the UN-Official version of numpy or the 64bit nature of windows or both?

Maybe I have to do some further configurations with Geany in order to introduce numpy to it?
Any suggestions in order to solve this Dilemma would be appreciated.

Comment: check that the Geany uses the same python where numpy is installed. Print sys.executable, sys.path from python console and from Geany, compare

Comment: Guys... "What kind of questions can I ask here?" ... "software tools commonly used by programmers", should this be off topic?